# AppEngine, python-oauth2 and Context.IO; consumer key not sent with request

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth

I'm having a very strange issue with AppEngine and the Context.IO API.

I'm using a the [contextIO2](https://github.com/contextio/contextIO2) library, which uses [python-oauth2](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2).

When I try out the library (contextIO2) via the terminal, I get no problems (or at least, not yet. But I've tried it several dozen times across a couple of days without problem).

But when running code on AppEngine, I ***sometimes*** get a `401 Authorization Invalid consumer key` error. I'm not sure what causes it, since one minute the request goes fine, then when I try the request again I get the `401`, then after a while it will be fine, then not fine again, so on.

I emailed Context.IO support, and he said that when he tries the url of my app and got the error, "oauth_consumer_key doesn't seem to be correctly transmitted". What could be causing this? AppEngine messing up the request? pythoan-oauth2 bug? contextIO2 bug?

Here's one of my handlers' code:

```
class ReceiveConnectTokenHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        contextio_token = self.request.get('contextio_token')
        cio = ContextIO(API_KEY, API_SECRET)
        # get token's associated email
        try:
            token = cio.get_connect_token(contextio_token)
        except RequestError, e:
            if e.status_code == 404:
                self.response.write(
                    'Token %s not found. ' % contextio_token)
                return
            raise e
        account = token.account
        if not account or not account.email_addresses:
            self.response.write(
                'Token %s has no email associated with it yet.' % contextio_token)
            return
        email = account.email_addresses[0]
        # clear email's memcache
        memcache.delete_multi(['accounts', 'no_account'], namespace=email)
        self.response.write(
            '''%s is now connected with Context.IO. Please verify in the
            gadget that you have granted access. You can close this window.''' % email
        )
```

It's just a simple GET on `https://api.context.io/2.0/connect_tokens/{{token}}`

Comment: It was a bug in the contextIO2 library. How do I close a topic?

Comment: Can you answer with a bug-report/fix for it? That might help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting answer as per Greg's suggestion.

The issue was that the contextIO2 library defined it's `request_uri` method by:

```
def request_uri(uri, method='GET', params={}, headers={}):
```

which is a common Python pitfall ([#5 in this list](http://www.zephyrfalcon.org/labs/python_pitfalls.html)). I've notified Context.IO support and have sent a pull request.